# An equivalent of IceCast but for Live Video Streaming?

Tags: streaming, flash, video-streaming

I am looking for a solution to Stream live video like that :

```
A camera/webcam/video output ---> Stream server ---> Clients
```

And if possible multiple Stream Servers like this (like IceCast):

```
A camera/webcam/video output --> Master Stream server +---> Slave Stream Server ---> Clients
                                                      |                         `--> Clients
                                                      |
                                                       `--> Slave Stream Server ---> Clients
                                                                                `--> Clients
```

The clients will be in flash, so I think RTMP should be a good protocol, I've heard of Red5, is it good for that ? Does it scale ? I would like to get statistics (Amount of clients, Bandwidth, etc), is it possible with red5 ?

Do you know any other good solution to do that ? (Only free and if possible Open Source)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more free open-source server that broadcasts RTMP is [Erlyvideo](http://erlyvideo.org/).

Comment: Waw this one looks great...

Comment: Also check out [Unreal Media Server](http://www.umediaserver.net/umediaserver/overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

If Flash (and it's proprietary video codec dependence) is not a problem for you, Red5 if the most stable "free software" solution known.

Else, take a look to GISS project (based on icecast2 that is able to stream OGG videos):
http://giss.tv/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Or icecast2 itself, that now include master-relay architecture.

Now videos could be played with HTML5 video tag falling back to cortado java applet.

Any case, all this will change soon with VP8.

Comment: Does HTML5 video have support for live streaming?

Answer (score 1):

[**Gstreamer**](http://www.gstreamer.net/) has all the capabilities you are talking about. It also supports RTMP.
The main problem would be to set up the whole thing because gstreamer can be complex.

It is often best to find program directly integrating gstreamer instead.